# Typescript: How do I get the real "this"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm going through the [learn.knockoutjs.com](http://learn.knockoutjs.com) tutorial and I'm at step 4 of the custom bindings tutorial.  There is the following JavaScript:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    // Give the first x stars the "chosen" class, where x <= rating
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    $("span", element).each(function(index) {
        $(this).toggleClass("chosen", index < observable());
    });
}
```

I have translated it to the following TypeScript:

```
update: (element, valueAccessor) => {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    $("span", element).each(index => {
        $(this).toggleClass('chosen', index < observable())
    });
}
```

This creates the following, where a _this variable is created to preserve the scope of the "update" function, rather than the internal "span" function.

```
update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var _this = this;
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    $("span", element).each(function (index) {
        $(_this).toggleClass('chosen', index < observable());
    });
}
```

The problem is with `$(_this)`.  How do I get TypeScript to give me the real `$(this)`.

Comment: @Esailija has the best solution by far. Simply don't use `$(this)` at all, but use the named parameter to the `each` callback instead. Basically, you should **never** use the implicit `this` in an `each` callback. Besides the problems you're having here, it is very bad for readability. The named parameter solves it much more cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the typescript doing `_this` is the more intuitive one for many, in fact code like this causes multiple duplicates per day on Stackoverflow:

```
  update: function() {
     $(elem).click(function(){
          this.save();
     });
  }
```

`this` is not the same `this` because in js `this` works differently from other languages - it has a separate binding for every function call.

Typescript would make the above work as expected by many newcomers to js:

```
  update: function() {
     //this is the object with update, save methods etc
     $(elem).click( () => {
          this.save();  //this is still the object with update, save methods etc
     });
  }
```

---

There is usually a way to refer to what you want even when using fat arrow:

```
update: function() {
    $(elem).click( (event) => {
        $(event.currentTarget).hide() //same as $(this).hide() with normal function
        this.save(); //Stays intuitive to non-javascripters
    });
}
```

Or with your example:

```
update: function() {
    $("span", element).each( (index, elem) => {
        $(elem).toggleClass('chosen', index < observable())
        this.save(); //stays intuitive to non-javascripters
    });
}
```

Of course for experienced Javascripters that are used to the JS-behavior of `this`, it might not be so intuitive.

Btw I am not 100% on the typescript syntax...

Comment: Your last version is by far the best solution. Don't use `$(this)` at all!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple.  Do not use a lambda.

```
update: (element, valueAccessor) => {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    $("span", element).each(function (index) {
        $(this).toggleClass('chosen', index < observable())
    });
}
```

Note that the difference is that this code uses `... element).each(function (index)...` instead of the lambda

I do not understand why so if someone could post why, that'd be great.

Comment: don't you hate when you post a question and then quickly find the solution? :)

Comment: @Pointy it uses `function (index) {}` instead of `index => {}`

Comment: I think the answer to 'why' is simply 'by design'. As you have discovered, fat arrows generate a little extra JS to make it easier to preserve the current scope. See section 4.9 of the spec: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf

Comment: In typescript a lambda will declare an exterior _this variable which will save the "real" value of 'this'.  Anywhere that you reference 'this' inside of the lambda gets compiled down to '_this', hence resulting in a different 'this' value.

Answer (score 1):

Esailija has the right idea here: don't use `$(this)` in the callback at all. Your code will be much cleaner with a named parameter.

As another example of how that helps, consider this simple jQuery plugin:

```
// Set a random opacity on each of the elements in a jQuery object
jQuery.fn.randomOpacity = function() {
    return this.each( function() {
        $(this).css({ opacity: Math.random() });
    });
};
```

Ouch. Can a piece of code possibly get any more confusing than that? `this` appears on two lines in a row, and it means *completely different things*.

Instead, use the named parameter:

```
// Set a random opacity on each of the elements in a jQuery object
jQuery.fn.randomOpacity = function() {
    return this.each( function( i, element ) {
        $(element).css({ opacity: Math.random() });
    });
};
```

That is much more clear.